# Genrate sequence thats its limit is the supremum of a set

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded above set.

Prove that exists a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n \in A$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = sup(A)$$.

I thought about: for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ taking $a_n \in A - (- \infty, a_{n-1}]$
Is that a good idea?

Comment: My guess is that you meant “sequence”, not “series”.

Answer (score 1):

Close but not quite.

There are a few things you overlooked.

1) Its possible that $(a_n, \sup A)$ need not have any values at all.  This can only happen if $\sup A \in A$.  For example take a finite set $A$ or the set $(0,1) \cup \{2\}$.

In the case that $\sup A \in A$ then $A$ has a max element.  There's nothing in the definition of sequence that the terms be unique.  In this case just take $a_k = \sup A$ for all $k$.  That'll do.  This is not an interesting case.

*MUCH* more interesting is when $\sup A \not\in A$.  In this case $\max A$ does not exist and $A$ is infinite.

In this case $(a_n, \sup A)$ *will* never be non empty and you *can* inductively find $a_n < a_{n+1} < a_{n+2} < .......... < \sup A$.

But

2) there's no reason to assume $\lim a_n = \sup A$.  Instead you might have $\lim a_n = m$ for some $m < \sup A$.

For example.  Suppose $A = (0, 2)$ and you chose $a_k = 1 - \frac 1k$.  Then $\lim a_n = 1 < \sup A = 2$.

Can you work around this?

> Let $a_k \in (\sup A - \frac 1k)$.  Because $\sup A$ is least upper bound $\sup A - \frac 1k$ is not an upper bound and so an $a_k\in (\sup A- \frac 1k, \sup A); a_k\in A$ will always exist.  And for any $\epsilon > 0$ if $n > \frac 1\epsilon$ then $\sup A - \epsilon < \sup A - \frac 1n < a_n <\sup A$. so $\lim a_n = \sup A$.

.

> Note: your idea that $a_{n} < a_{n+1} < \sup A$, was an *EXCELLENT* idea and very good first step to solving.  But ultimately wasn't necessary.  But could still be used.  Maybe, let $a_{n+1} \in (\frac {\sup A + a_n}2, \sup A)$ (that is, $a_{n+1}$ is between $\sup A$ and the midpoint between $\sup A$ and $a_n$.)

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by$a_k \in (\sup A - \frac{1}{k})$ the right hand side is a number, not a group so why you using in $\in$

Comment: Oops, a typo.  I meant $a_k \in (\sup A -\frac 1k, \sup A)$.  I was trying to use the OP's language and notation.

Answer (score 0):

Put $\;M:=\sup A\;$ , then by the very definition of supremum of a real set, we have that for any natural number $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ there exists $\;a_n\in A\;$ s.t.

$$M-\frac1n<a_n\le M$$

Now make your choice and use the squeeze theorem...